# Spring BeanPostProcessor not get called its implemented bean , but invoke for all other beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-bean

my **bean.xml**

hi friends.., i am just learning spring . i implement the interface  BeanPostProcessor in HelloWorld.java . its methods invoked for all other beans , but not itself(Helloworld.java bean)

```
 <bean id="helloWorld" class="com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorld" >     </bean>  
   <!-- Definition for textEditor bean -->
   <bean id="textEditor" class="com.tutorialspoint.TextEditor">
      <property name="spellChecker" ref="spellChecker"/>
   </bean>

   <!-- Definition for spellChecker bean -->
   <bean id="spellChecker" class="com.tutorialspoint.SpellChecker">
   </bean>
```

**Helloworld.java**

```
public class HelloWorld implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String name)
            throws BeansException {

        System.out.println();       
        System.out.println(bean.getClass().getName() +"---------------"+name+"--->This is after bean initialized ");

        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String name)
            throws BeansException {

        System.out.println(bean.getClass().getName() +"---------------"+name+"----------->This is before bean initialized ");

        return bean;
    }
}
```

**main program**

```
public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String arg[])throws Exception{
        AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Bean.xml");        

    }
    }
```

**my output is**

```
com.tutorialspoint.SpellChecker---------------spellChecker----------->This is before bean initialized 

com.tutorialspoint.SpellChecker---------------spellChecker--->This is after bean initialized 

com.tutorialspoint.TextEditor---------------textEditor----------->This is before bean initialized 

com.tutorialspoint.TextEditor---------------textEditor--->This is after bean initialized
```

why BeanPostProcessor interface methods not invoked for  HelloWorld.java  ..,but invoked for  other unrelated beans which is not implementing BeanPostProcessor interface ..?

Comment: @mtyurt please look again my bean.xml . i declared HelloWorld class as Hello bean as first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

any bean implementing `BeanPostprocessor` works as bean postprocessor for all beans.Please refer [URL](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) for more details.It is clearly mentioned that `ApplicationContexts can autodetect BeanPostProcessor beans in their bean definitions and apply them to any beans subsequently created. **Plain bean factories allow for programmatic registration of post-processors, applying to all beans created through this factory**.`

Do you want a specific bean having some initializing code then implement `InitializingBean` as below

```
package org.studyspring.beanfactory    
public class HelloWorld implements InitializingBean {
        private String name;

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }


        @Override
        public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
            System.out.println(this.getClass().getName() +"---------------name = "+name+"--->This is after bean initialized ");
        }
    }
```

add entry for this bean in XML

```
 <bean id="helloWorld" class="org.studyspring.beanfactory.HelloWorld">
        <property name="name" value="Shirish"/>
    </bean>
```

or alternatively you can have init and destroy methods for each bean as below

```
package org.studyspring.beanfactory;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;


public class HelloWorld1  {
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }



    public void init() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName() +"---------------name = "+name+"--->This is before bean initialized");
    }

    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName() +"---------------name = "+name+"--->This is after bean destroyed ");
    }
}
```

register your bean as below in XML

```
<bean id="helloWorld1" class="org.studyspring.beanfactory.HelloWorld1" init-method="init" destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="name" value="Shirish"/>
</bean>
```

Additionally if you follow common practice for naming init & destroy methods then you can define those methods in `<beans>` as below

```
<beans default-init-method="init" default-destroy-method="destroy">
```

with above the beans which have init and destory methods available they will be called upon initialization and destructions of those beans

Comment: thanks for your answer . but i think it is not acceptable . i implemented in one bean but how can it work as global one ..? any refernece

Comment: upvote for your super answer and other methods init,destoy, InitializingBean

Comment: then why it does not invoke HelloWorld bean...?

Comment: any answer for my question why it does not call helloworld bean and any reference for it

Comment: WoW!! amazingly described Sir... :) Very helpful.